# How to make a header responsive?

Tags: responsive-design, susy-compass

I am having the following HTML:

```
<div class='layout-wrap'>
  <div class='mod-header'>
    <a class='logo' href="#"></a>
    <nav>
      <a class="action" href="#">Join now</a>
      <ul class="tour">
        <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="search">
        <li><a class="find" href="#">search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

See also:

http://jsfiddle.net/mulderp/fZ8cW/

And CSS:

```
.logo {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    float: left;
    width: 16rem;
}

nav {
   float: right;
   display: block;
}

.mod-header nav a {
   float: left;
}
```

What is a minimum responsive layout solution (e.g. with Susy) such that:

- a.logo is always visible (also for small screens)
- a.action is always visible (also for small screens)
- a.find is always visible
- ul.tour is hidden for small screens

Not sure if this easily possible, but it would be helpful to know if yes.

**Edit:**

Narrower question: How to prevent the break in nav of the right part for small questions, and hide the ul.tour ?

[image: nav breaks]

Susy SASS:

```
.mod-header
  @include container
  clear: both
  border: 2px red solid
  +rem('height', 70px)

  .logo
    text-indent: -9999px
    float: left
    +rem('width', 120px)
    +rem('height', 29px)
    +rem('margin', 20px 0)
    border: 2px blue solid
    +data-uri-bg('logo.png')

  nav
    @include span-columns(4,12)
    border: 2px blue solid
    float: right
    +rem('margin', 20px 0)
    +rem('height', 29px)

    ul
      li
        float: left
        +rem('margin', 0 8px)
```

Comment: This is very easily possible, but any answer requires a lot of decisions about how you want it to look and move. There are too many different ways you could do it. Why don't you give it a try, and ask questions if you run into more specific problems?

Comment: Sorry, indeed I have a couple of questions here. I narrowed it down to a first question on the nav part.

Comment: I'm sure you can hide an element (`display: none;` would be one way). Is the question really about how to use media-queries with Susy to control *when* the item is hidden and when it's shown? Here's the documentation for [Susy breakpoints](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-responsive). To keep the line-breaks out, you have to make sure the elements never add up to more than 100%. After hiding `.tour`, you have two items left, so you can give them each 50% width, or give each 2-of-4 columns using Susy.